# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC, expecting T_CLASS in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\class.engine.php on line 75

Tags: php, syntax, parse-error

I'm getting this error of :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC, expecting T_CLASS in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\class.engine.php on line 75

I don't know what the problem is i've tried everything really but still nothing

Codes around Line 75

```
final public function disconnect()
{
    global $core;
    if($this->connected)
    {
        if($this->mysql['close'])
        {
            $this->connected = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $core->systemError('MySQL Engine', 'MySQL could not disconnect.');
        }
    }
}
```

Any help? :)

Comment: Does this function appear inside the rest of your class definition `{}` ? Sounds like maybe your `class { ... }` closes prematurely before this.

Comment: Yes it does, how may i fix this?

Comment: Can you post the entire contents of the file? You can share it at http://pastebin.com/ and comment the link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ity0eiJC

Comment: See here: http://pastebin.com/iwSXr1Qa missing one closing bracket at line 55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this function appear inside the rest of your class definition `{}` ? Sounds like maybe your `class { ... }` closes prematurely before this.

Turns out you were declaring a new function within a function, because of one missing closing bracket.

See here: http://www.pastebin.com/iwSXr1Qa the error was at line 55